# SQL order within cases, DESC and ASC odd behavior

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm having a tough time getting this SQL statement to produce the result I want. This is the code I'm using:

`SELECT * FROM "Contracts" WHERE 
"productType" = 'RINbuy' AND
"clearTime" IS NULL
order by
  case when "holdTime" is not null then 0 else 1 end,
  case when "holdTime" is not null then 
  "generationTime" 
  else "contractLimitPrice" 
  end;`

I'm trying to get results that look like this

`+---------------+----------+--------------------+
|generationTime | holdTime | contractLimitPrice |
+---------------+----------+--------------------+
| 1             |5         |  1.282             |
| 4             |6         |  1.535             |
| 2             |NULL      |  1.911             |
| 3             |NULL      |  1.764             |
+---------------+----------+--------------------+`

But I'm getting this:

`+---------------+----------+--------------------+
|generationTime | holdTime | contractLimitPrice |
+---------------+----------+--------------------+
| 1             |5         |  1.282             |
| 4             |6         |  1.535             |
| 3             |NULL      |  1.764             |
| 2             |NULL      |  1.911             |
+---------------+----------+--------------------+`

The last two rows are switched. I've tried adding DESC and ASC in every possible permutation as well as swapping the 0 and the 1. I have also tried switching the order of the case statements.
**EDIT:**
My end goal is to have the table sorted by the generationTime if the holdTime is NOT NULL and  then sorted DESC by contractLimitPrice if the holdTime IS NULL.

Comment: Can you post the output for two cases: (1) add DESC right before the final semicolon; (2) add DESC inside the quotes of the field names of the second case statement, like `generationTime DESC`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Case (1): The bottom 2 rows are correct row but the top two rows are flipped. Case (2): I get an error when I put DESC in the quotes `ERROR:  column "generationTime DESC" does not exist
LINE 6:   case when "holdTime" is not null then "generationTime DESC...`

Comment: The example does not clarify all possible cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a second look: The single `CASE` statement cannot do what you seem to expect! Seems like you want to sort rows with `"holdTime" IS NULL` by `"contractLimitPrice"` and the rest by `"generationTime"`.
If so, use this instead:

```
ORDER BY "holdTime" IS NULL
       , CASE WHEN "holdTime" IS NULL THEN "contractLimitPrice" END DESC
       , CASE WHEN "holdTime" IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE "generationTime" END
```

`"holdTime" IS NULL` ... `FALSE` (0) sorts before `TRUE` (1).

This also alleviates any problems that might arise from type casting.

The `DESC` at the end of the second item is derived from your comment. Was not clear from your question.

For your original version:
A `CASE` statement only works for column of the same type (or types that can be cast automatically. You did not disclose your actual data types. Either way, you would cast to the type with more precision if the types are not identical.

The error message:

```
> ERROR: column "generationTime DESC" does not exist LINE 6:
```

points to a plain syntax error, which is *not* in your query.

Comment: The data type of each column is double. I tried both pieces of code you suggested. Both resulted in the same results that I got with my code. I need to figure out how to get the contract limit price to sort DESC when the holdTime is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the data types.  One value is a date and the other numeric (or character).  So, the results are being implicitly converted.

You can just do:

```
order by (case when "holdTime" is not null then 0 else 1 end),
         (case when "holdTime" is not null then "generationTime" end),
         (case when "holdtime" is null then "contractLimitPrice" end)
```

You don't have to worry about the extra `NULL` values being produced when the second and third conditions are not true.  The first condition ensures that the groups based on having a valid `holdtime` appear together.

EDIT:

Did you try this?

```
order by (case when "holdTime" is not null then 0 else 1 end),
         (case when "holdTime" is not null then  "generationTime"
               else "contractLimitPrice" 
          end) desc;
```

With only two values, it is a little hard to tell exactly what is happening.  But it looks like they are being sorted in ascending order.

Comment: For the purpose of the question I changed the date to a human readable date. The time is stored as unix time, stored as a double, and the contractLimitPrice is also stored as a double. I tried your suggestion anyway and I got the same output. Sorry for not putting the "real" values, I'll edit my OP.